# wordpress menu_order not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know what is wrong with menu_order but the posts are not displayed as I want. Here is what I mean

I have 3 posts in my blog. Here is how db looks like

```
id ..... menu_order
56 ..... 2
59 ..... 5
65 ..... 3
```

index.php (my custom theme)

I want to display only image so here is the code that I use

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     $images = get_children(
                            array( 'post_parent'    => $post->ID, 
                                   'post_type'      => 'attachment', 
                                   'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
                                   'orderby'        => 'menu_order', 
                                   'order'          => 'DESC', 
                                   'numberposts' => 999 ) 
                                );
     if( $images ) 
         {
            $total_images = count( $images );
                $image = array_shift( $images );
                echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'full', 0, array('id' => 'photo'));
         }

    endwhile; // end of the loop. 
    ?>
```

The problem is that the posts are displayed in order with id 65,59,56 and not as I expect 59,65, 56

What is wrong with this ?

Comment: you should ask this question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have the same exact problem :(

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code. It will solve your issue

'sort_column' => 'menu_order'

Answer (score 0):

I would use `get_posts()` with the same parameters instead. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts).

Comment: I get the same result using get_posts

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this `menu_order` isn't what you'd think, eg. the order you have chosen on your site custom menu. Instead it's the order you set every page under writing... This is not what I want either so I made this solution:

sort_column=menu_order only sorts pages based on their order in writing not the order you set in view > menus (translated), if you want that you can do like this:

```
    $children = get_pages('child_of='. $topID); 

    // 'sort_column=menu_order' <-- only sorts by post order in writing mode (page > edit) not the menu order set in view > menus
    // wp_nav_menu has what we need, let's sort it the same way.
    $options = array(
        'container' =>  '',
        'echo'      =>  false,

    );                      
    $nav = wp_nav_menu($options);       
    $nav = strip_tags($nav);        
    $nav = str_replace("\r", '', $nav);
    $nav = explode("\n", $nav);
    //print_r($nav);
    $newChildren = array();
    foreach ($nav as $item) {
        $item = trim($item);
        $run = true;
        for ($c = 0; $c < count($children) && run; $c++) {              
            $child = $children[$c];
            if (strcmp($child->post_title, $item) == 0 && !in_array($child, $newChildren)) {
                $newChildren[] = $child;                    
                $run = false;
            }
        }

        // Adding the children the nav_menu is lacking, not sure why not all sub-children 
        //  are added to the first child here..(works but don't know why :/)
        if ($run == true) {
            for ($c = 0; $c < count($children) && run; $c++) {              
                $child = $children[$c];     
                if (!in_array($child, $newChildren)) {
                    $newChildren[] = $child;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    $children = $newChildren;
```

Answer (score 0):

when you populate the menu, add `sort_column=menu_order` :

```
 <ul class="main-nav">

    <?php wp_list_pages('&title_li=&depth=2&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>

 </ul>
```